# I have errors in debugging my application project in flutter

Tags: flutter, debugging, dart-pub

My laptop computer cannot enable android emulator because It doesn't have Hyper-v (please I need help on how to install Hyper-v on windows 10). I connected my android device to my laptop computer and I started debugging and this Is the error I got

Exception in thread "main" java.net.socketexception: software caused connection abort: socket write error

Am a flutter newbie actually but am not a programming newbie. Am an android app developer I work with Android Studio on my previous laptop computer.

I was expecting the best out of Flutter
Please help

NB: i need a flutter mentor

Comment: This question need more details. Please run `flutter doctor -v` and copy/paste result in your question.

Answer (score 0):

https://youtu.be/FaytvySV04s

**I hope this video helps you. watch the video until the end and I think it will be useful.**